# Using facebook Oauth2 - meta requesting access to the app/site & will restrict us in 6 days

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

We are planning to offer users the option to login using facebook Oauth2. This has been setup and is working in test but we received this warning today, see below screenshot:

*We are unable to review all features on this app because payment or membership is required to access the full functionality. Any access codes that may have been previously provided to us have expired.*

I cannot grant facebook access to this site, it contains sensitive information.
We also have not had this issue with google.

Would appreciate help understanding if we have done something wrong when setting up facebook Oauth2, or is this just facebook/meta policy?

[image]